# Get a pdf (iText) through api REST using Spring MVC and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-mvc, pdf-generation

I have a interface in Java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/getPdf", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"content-type=application/json"}
@ResponseBody public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPdf(@RequestBody final DatosPdf datosPdf);
```

Implementation:

```
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPdf(@RequestBody final DatosPdf datosPdf) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream archivo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Document documento = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, archivo);
    documento.open();
    documento.add(new Paragraph("Hello world"));
    documento.close();
    archivo.close();

    String filename = "hello.pdf";
    byte[] documentContent = archivo.toByteArray();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData(filename, filename);
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(documentContent, headers, HttpStatus.OK);

    return response;
}
```

Function Javascript

```
HttpSrv.post('api/getPdf', datosPdf).then(function(pdf) {
//CODE TO OPEN PDF FILE
}, function(errorResponse){
});
```

In the FRONT I receive the byte[]
The Java implementation is correct?
How I can open the pdf in the browser?

Thanks!!

Comment: did you got the solution ?